# jquery shortcuts not working on IE

Tags: jquery

Hi 
I am using jQuery.hotkeys.js plug in for key board shortcut. All other shortcuts are working fine but f1 is not working as expected in IE. 
On 'f1' keypress it binds the shortcut but is being called more than one time and also it opens help window as well.

the code is like this:

```
 $(document).bind('keydown', 'f1', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        alert('some message');
         window.event.keyCode = 0;
        return false;
});
```

please give me idea for this.

Thanks

Munish

Answer (score 3):

In Internet Explorer, the <kbd>F1</kbd> key cannot be cancelled from the keydown handler.  You can attach to the [`onhelp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536937(VS.85).aspx) event instead:

```
window.onhelp = function () {
    return false;
}
```

The firing twice issue is possibly a bug in the plugin code, if it's only occurring in Internet Explorer you can work around it by using the `onhelp` event exclusively:

```
if ("onhelp" in window) // IE
    window.onhelp = function() {
        alert("some message");
        return false;
    }
else // Others
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'f1', function(evt) {
        alert('some message');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: thanks it worked but the bind function is being called more then one time.

Comment: @munish: try using the `onhelp` function exclusively in Internet Explorer, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why do you want to override <kbd>F1</kbd>? It is a well known convention that will launch the help for the desktop application (not your web application).

There may be no way around this, especially since you use `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()` *and* `return false`.

Comment: what i want to do on 'F1' key press is to show my own help and it is working well in FireFox so i want the same in IE as well. Please give me some idea to do this

Comment: AFAIK firefox is the only that allows overriding its shortcuts (CTRL+R, etc...) in Javascript.